# Moving to next view in popover displaying UITableView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have created an application for iPhone interface which displays a `UITableView` as its rootviewcontroller. When we select any of its row, it opens the corresponding detailViewController, we select the value from there and it is displayed in the cells of `UITableView` in masterViewController. This application was running perfectly fine in iPhone simulator as desired.

Now I want to incorporate this application to an iPad application. For that purpose, I have created a `UIPopOver` and assigned the masterViewController to the popover. Now the problem is, `UITableView` is initially shown in the popover. But when we select any row, next view doesn't appear in popover as it appeared when application was running solely for iPhone. How should I make it work so that I can import the application with original functionality in `UIPopOver`?

Comment: Can you post some code, how you are adding detailViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are pushing DetailViewController from your masterViewController.But your masterviewController should implement NavigationController, I mean while displaying masterViewController(your tableviewcontroller) in popover you should do as follows:

```
MasterViewController *theMasterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navCont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theMasterViewController]; 
    [theMasterViewController release];
    UIPopoverController *popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navCont];
    popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 400);
    [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:btn.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

and when user selects any row, then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath do as follows:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanx a lot :) It really helped... I was making the mistake of initializing popovercontroller with only masterviewcontroller... Now I have passed navigation controller and it is switching between views perfectly fine :)

Comment: Now a new problem arises... My delegate methods are not working and values from detailViewController are not being passed to masterViewController :( It was working fine when tested outside uipopover controller... Plz need further help

Comment: Which delegate methods not working and how you are passing values from detailviewcontroller to masterviewcontroller?Better place a different question with some code.

Comment: I am using protocols to pass values from detailViewController to masterViewController which were being called when a button is pressed and they were working fine and passing values successfully... Now they are not passing values when used in uipopover... Sorry am new here... Cant figure out how to paste code

Comment: First thing, I guess on button click you are popping your detailviewcontroller and second thing, you can paste your code in the same area where you are writing your question. Click on Edit your question and paste the code there.

Comment: Right so in my detailViewController... When I click the done button, self.selectedVlaue is passed using protocol from this code...

- (void)done {
    self.selectedValue = (int)self.stepper.value;
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(stepperViewController:selectedValue:)]) {
        [self.delegate stepperViewController:self selectedValue:self.selectedValue];
    }
    [self.navigationController  popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

Comment: And it is received in masterViewController in this method...

- (void)stepperViewController:(StepperViewController *)viewController selectedValue:(NSInteger)value {
    self.selectedFontSize = value;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: I know the issue now. I have checked that values are being passed successfully but UITableview in initial popOverView is not being reloaded... And one more thing, uitableview has been altered when showing in uipopover. It had 2 sections with 1 and 3 rows respectively. But in popover, it is displaying a single section with 4 rows. How to reloadData in table view of uipopovercontroller? And is it different from table view of rootViewController which is being passed to it?

Comment: TableView displayed in popover is a simple/normal tableview only, it is not different from your normal tableview.I think you should check how you are displaying your tableview.Problem is in the code only because tableview does not depend upon how you are displaying it in popover or modal or something else.

Comment: [self.tableView reloadData] is not working for tableview in masterViewController in uipopover. Dont know why it is not calling uitableview data source methods? If this happens, my problem will be solved

Comment: I checked and for me its working fine.It is calling datasource methods.Have you put breakpoint and checked? And what changes you are loading in delegate method?

Comment: I have figured out the mistake. I was making my view controller for subclass of uitableviewcontroller and then created a separate property for uitableview. Compiler was confused which tableview to reload :p Thanx a lot for ur help :)